# Fill a small gap between 2 displays in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, display

Here's a picture of my monitor setup:

[image]

I'm wondering if it's possible to fill the gap between display 5 and display 3, so that I don't have to pull the mouse down and move around it.

**Edit**: Without having to reposition any of the displays.

Comment: Can you drag Screen 5 to the right so it touches Screen 3, does it work then?

Comment: @RMarkwald It does, but then screen 5 will be misaligned on the left side with screen 4.  I didn't want to have to reposition anything.